# Canceling secondary javascript event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that when clicked sets the text in an input text field.

The input text field has an onchange event that fires when someone puts in text, however, I don't want this onchange event to fire when its value is injected from clicking the button described above.

Is this possible?

Note that this is not related to event bubbling/propagation of the click event on the button

Comment: Simply setting the `value` attribute of the `<input>` element will not trigger the `change` event by itself. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the event on the text field to a .blur() or .keyup(), which would only detect if the text field loses focus or the user inputs text manually (respectively).

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the source of the event like this:

```
var sourceElement = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
```

...the have an if statement to switch.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible IF you change the onchange event of your input field to an "input propertychange" event.
So you could simply to that `$('input').on("input propertychange",function(){});`